# Filling XFA data to xfa form pdf with ITEXT 7 in C#

Tags: itext7

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceXfaPath);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(exportPdf);

PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer, new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
XfaForm xfa = form.GetXfaForm();
xfa.FillXfaForm(new FileStream(exportXfaXml,FileMode.Open));

xfa.Write(pdfDoc);
pdfDoc.Close();
reader.Close();
```

codes are above:

but it doesn't create pdf document, I'm not sure why it doesn't create it.

I just tried `xfa.FillXfaForm(new FileStream(exportXfaXml,FileMode.Open));` to `xfa.FillXfaForm(XmlReader.Create(path));`

but it shows me same error

Comment: Please add the error or stack trace you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void customGenerate(string sourceFilePath, string destinationtFilePath, string replacementXmlFilePath)
{
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(sourceFilePath);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms, '\0', true))
        //using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms))
        {
            XfaForm xfaForm = new XfaForm(pdfReader);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(replacementXmlFilePath);
            
            xfaForm.DomDocument = doc;
            xfaForm.Changed = true;
            XfaForm.SetXfa(xfaForm, stamper.Reader, stamper.Writer);

            stamper.Close();
        }

        var bytes = ms.ToArray();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(destinationtFilePath, bytes);
        ms.Close();
    }
    pdfReader.Close();
}
```

This is my code to add Javacript to XFA PDF.

I'm going to add JavaScript[handle button , checkbox] to XFA pdf with avoid signature.

Comment: I can't find this class "XmlDocument" xD